# Search Body for a Keyword

Tags: support, data-explorer

Is it possible to search the body for a keyword answered by a particular user in a particular tag?

Example: Search for string "prototype" by user "xx" for tag "javascript"

I want to write a query for the same in the data explorer

Answer (score 1):

[Sure](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:xx%20%5Bjavascript%5D%20prototype).  That's what the [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search) is there for.

Comment: I meant how will write a query for it?

Comment: @user1814374 Did you click the link?  I wrote out that exact query for you.

Comment: @Servy He means SQL query.

Comment: @Servy This question is tagged with [meta-tag:data-explorer], not [meta-tag:search].

Comment: @animuson It was edited in after I posted the answer.

Comment: @Servy The tag was there before you answered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1085091?tagname=c%23&word=prototype&UserId=22656) that does search for a word in one specific tag for one specific user.

```sql
select p.id as [Post Link]
from posts p
inner join posttags pt 
        on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id) -- use question if an answer
inner join tags t 
        on t.id = pt.tagid
where t.tagname = ##tagname:string##
and p.owneruserid = ##userid:int##
and p.posttypeid in (1, 2) -- Q = 1, A = 2
and body like '%##word##%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai
```

This can work because there are enough criteria to have a small resultset that would need to be scanned for the word in the `body` field, as the `LIKE` statement can't be optimized for using an index.

When run today, looking for C# posts from Jon Skeet that use the word *prototype* this will be the result:

[image: jon skeet's c# posts about prototype]

SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday 03:00 UTC. Don't forget the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) and visit [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).